# Flutter Kotlin version 1.9

Tags: flutter, kotlin, build, compiler-errors, apk

version: 1.0.0+1  environment:   sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0' dependencies:   flutter:     sdk: flutter    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6   bloc: ^8.1.2   flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3   flutter_svg: ^2.0.9   google_fonts: ^6.1.0   equatable: ^2.0.5   mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.8.0   flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0   http: ^1.1.2   pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1   shimmer: ^3.0.0   google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.3   geolocator: ^10.1.0 #  location: ^5.0.0   flutter_rating_stars: ^1.0.3+4   flutter_polyline_points: ^2.0.0   url_launcher: ^6.2.3   intl: ^0.19.0   googleapis: ^12.0.0   flutter_slidable: ^3.0.1   firebase_core: ^2.24.2   firebase_messaging: ^14.7.10   # overlay_support: ^2.1.0   permission_handler: ^11.2.0

error Text  -

```
: C:/Users/azimz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/889ce5bd12f1117e5357d5fcdb5e1305/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:/Users/azimz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:/Users/azimz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:/Users/azimz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:/Users/azimz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.0/cd65c21cfd1eec4d44ef09f9f52b6d9f8a720636/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

-- Build Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I build the apk it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a mismatch in the Kotlin version that you have installed in the Android Studio and the one that the Flutter Project uses. Try to match the two.
You can checkout your kotlin version by going into the build.gradle file inside the android folder of your flutter project

Comment: How can I find the Kotlin version of my Flutter project?

Comment: You should find it inside Project folder > android > build.gradle file